# Ncurses multi-key input

Tags: ncurses

I am creating a console based application in C using ncurses that takes individual key input but also reads in key combinations.  For example when the user presses both the <kbd>S</kbd> key and the <kbd>F</kbd> key, I want it to run some function.  Is there some function like getch() for multi-key combinations?

Thanks!

Comment: Someone found a workaround to this problem. (I know this post is old, but it's better to redirect people who'd land here)
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144558

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer Yes though it depends on what you're actually after. You can't for example detect two keys at the same time or modifier keys. For example try `cat -v` and type a shifted up arrow (it's the same as the up arrow). I'm not sure if it will work for all sequences either. I commented that there's also the function `getstr()` (and its size-restricted counterpart `getnstr()`) which is like several calls to `getch()` but this won't work for all scenarios unfortunately. Still it's a possible way to work out some of the issues.

Comment: @Pryftan honestly I haven't been into code for the past few months. I can't tell anything anymore now, but this is still some interesting information to learn.

Comment: @Jean-MarcZimmer I know how that goes. And truly there are many ways to skin a cat in computers. Just thought I'd say that there's an easier way - not just for you but others - because if the goal is to have a sequence of chars then those functions are much cleaner to use.

Answer (score 3):

No ncurses does not provide anything like that -- ncurses is from an era where input was just a likely to be over a serial port as a directly connected keyboard.

If you need know if 2 keys are pressed at the same time you will need to access the keyboard at a lower level.